# Find city weather code from command line

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to find city weather codes from the command line (example for Roissy-en-France,FR ; the code is `FRXX3828`)

So far I tried the tools at https://askubuntu.com/questions/390329 but none of them actually display the weather code.

Can you help ?

Comment: What command did you use and what did you get when using it? Any error messages? No one can help you without that.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather ugly, but it seems to work:

```bsh
# create a temporary file to store the curl output
$ tmpfile=$(mktemp)
# perform a search in the site https://weather.codes in the url
$ curl -v --silent "https://weather.codes/search/?q=Roissy+en+France" > "$tmpfile" 2> /dev/null
# extract the code
$ sed -z 's,.*<span>\([^<>]*\)</span>.*,\1,g' "$tmpfile"
FRXX3828
```

Of course this won't work if the page changes its html code or the search method